# UseEffect doesn't behave as expected -

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

When I refresh the page useEffect only render one function out of the two inside, and when I change routes it works normally.

I am using redux to set global state with the vehicles and dispatching the API in useEffect
so I have vehicles available all the time. however, the second function `vchStatusNumbers` that it should return the length of the array filtered as per its status , it only runs once, and when i add its state as dependency i get an infinite loop!

I need to understand how i should approach it?

Below is the component

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from "react";
import StatisticBanner from "./StatisticBanner";
import {getAllVehicles,fetchVehiclesReport } from "./vehiclesReducer";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

 const Home= ()=> {
  const {vehicles} = useSelector(getAllVehicles); // get the state
const [statusTotal, setStatusTotal] = useState({})
  const dispatch = useDispatch(); // dispatch fn to reducers



  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchVehiclesReport());
    vchStatusNumbers();
  }, [dispatch]);

  const vchStatusNumbers = () =>{
    const status = {}
    let availableLength = 0
    let parkedLength = 0
    let serviceLength = 0
      vehicles.map(vch=>{
      if(vch.status === 'available'){
        ++availableLength
        status.available = availableLength
    
      }
      if(vch.status === 'parked'){
        ++parkedLength
        status.parked = parkedLength
      }
      if(vch.status === 'service'){
        ++serviceLength
        status.service = serviceLength
      }
    })
  
    setStatusTotal (status)
  }

  return (
    <>
        <div style={{ margin: 20 }}>
          <StatisticBanner key={"statics"} statusTotal={statusTotal} />
        </div>
    </>
  );
}
export default   Home
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you add a dependency to an `useEffect` hook that ultimately updates *that* dependency value then this will cause render looping.

Seems `vchStatusNumbers` should be in a separate `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `vehicles` redux state value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  vchStatusNumbers();
}, [vehicles]);
```

This is because it is derived state from the `vehicles` data and won't be updated yet in the first effect that dispatches the action to update it.

Comment: Thank you Drew! I understand the life cyclic.however, I didn't know that I have to break useEffect according to the logic! it is interesting way! much appreciate it